# (a*b*c*...)%C1=C2, How to get random valid solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This algorithm is made to verify serial numbers. For example:

$$3\cdot6\cdot2\cdot9\cdot5\cdot5\cdot6 \bmod 32 \equiv 24$$

$32$ and $24$ are given, and now I need to generate valid numbers for the left. These numbers are in a certain range (this case $1$ to $9$) and will pose as serial numbers. Also the math is in integers.

But I'm stuck. I don't know how to find a solution. Can anyone point me in the right direction? This seems so simple =/

Comment: How many numbers are on the left?

Comment: it should be 25

Comment: Not a "mathy" solution, but a programmatic approach: Take the $n$th multiple of $32$, and subtract $24$.  If this number has 25 single-digit prime factors, then you're done--these 25 are the numbers on the LHS of the equation.  (This doesn't get *all* possible serial numbers, but it would give you some examples, I think.)

Comment: actually im not using 32 in my real approach. im using the overflow of unsigned int. so it would be (2^32)-1 and using multiple of this is kinda hard with normal datatypes. also i want to generate the serials with the help of a random generator. im open for programmatic solutions :D. also my serial should consist of alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a slicker way of going about this, but this is what came to my mind.

You are given that 3⋅6⋅2⋅9⋅5⋅5⋅6 mod 32 ≡ 24.

Then pick a pair, say 3⋅6=18. Well, 9⋅2=18 as well. So we can make that substitution and get:

9⋅2⋅2⋅9⋅5⋅5⋅6 mod 32 ≡ 24 as a rather unsatisfying alternative solution.

Comment: sadly this solution may work for a human brain, but a computer might have its problems with it. also this needs one working solution to begin with, which i dont have (the blablabl = 24 was just an example)